# Errno 22 Invalid argument...python3.exe: can't open file print.py

Tags: python, bash

I have these two scripts within the same folder, I'm working in Windows 10:

File `job.sh`

```
python3 print.py
```

File `print.py`

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
print('Hello World')
```

When I run `job.sh` I get the error,

`[Errno 22] Invalid argument7-32\python3.exe can't open file print.py`

But, after a lot of ways that I tried, I just noticed that only the first line is generating this error. So, If I modify the file `job.sh`

```
python3 print.py
python3 print.py
```

then the first line is generating the same error, whereas the second is showing the result.

Btw, if I write directly in cmd `python3 print.py` everything is fine.

I have no idea what is wrong with my `job.sh` script. Thanks for any help!

Comment: I really don't suggest calling your file `print.py` as this conflicts with the python built-in function.

Comment: @roganjosh Thanks for the suggestion! I just changed its name to `hello.py` and still the same error.

Comment: Attach the sh file. Maybe we can see something in it, which you didn't notice :\

Comment: The first line in `job.sh` may contain `\r\n` at the end of line. Please try to execute `od -c job.sh`.

Comment: @zvone here is the link to the .sh file: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Ew_0yOE_yg9gF47mqYwJjynJyqJqHBzM

Comment: @tshiono I run it and YES I have \r\n characters. I'm going to install `dos2unix`, if this is the way to fix it.

Comment: This is what is in the file: `'python3 hello.py\r\npython3 hello.py\r\npython3 hello.py'`

Comment: Yes, `dos2unix` would be a proper tool to check and fix the newline characters.

Comment: @tshiono, @zvone , i run `dos2unix job.sh` and it's working now. Thank you! I can accept a solution if any of you could find some time to add an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are some tips:

- don't use directly python3 to launch your python script, because it is already defining to be a python3 executable
- ensure it is executable
- like said in comments, don't use `print` as it is already an important keyword
- ensure you don't have wrong/bad ending like character (`\r\n` instead of `\n`)

Finally (let's call it `myScript.py` instead of `print.py`):

```
dos2unix job.sh
chmod +x myScript.py
```

And in your `job.sh` bash script, just call your now executable python script:

```
myScript.py
```

Comment: thank you or adding the solution. After I run `dos2unix` everything is fine. For curiosity, related to your first listed point, I tried now to remove the `python3` command, and despite that it's in the `.py` file, still I got an error saying that `job.sh command not found`.

Comment: Are you sure you used the `chmod` instruction to ensure your python script is executable? If so, could you post both scripts?

Comment: Yes, I have run the `cmod +x` and `chmod u+x`. I'll try to share my scripts, and let you know.

Comment: yep, it is fixed, but I have a new one if you can help :), I'll really appreciate any suggestion. I posted it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54390028/dont-understand-this-oserror-winerror-193-1-is-not-a-valid-win32-application)

Comment: Ok i'll check it 